# Namibia visa extension to full 90 day stay

Tags: south-african-citizens, visa-extensions, namibia

We have a South African passport. We got 50 days but we want to extend it to 90 days. We are currently in Walvisbaai visiting my brother's son. Do you pay for extension? Yesterday my husband went to ask about extension here in Walvisbaai; they told him N$80 plus. N$ 340 for what i don't know. Have days left, why must we pay? Got 40 days left.

Comment: I have submitted an edit suggestion to remove your email address.  A fundamental principle of this site is that replies should be public, here on the site, so that others with the same or a similar question can benefit from the information in the answers.  Please review the [help] for more information.  Thanks, and hope this helps.

Comment: Hard to say with certainty due to the lack of details in your question, but as a general rule, extensions of stay within a country are not guaranteed to be the maximum allowed by law.  The government official handling your request can choose to extend your stay by whatever time they feel appropriate, be it only a week or be it the full 90 days.

Comment: To make sure we've got the question right, you want to extend your stay in Namibia, right?